# Tutorials for beamer and other presentation packages

Tags: beamer, presentations, tutorials

As I decided to use LaTeX to make a presentation and I'm a newbie, I would like a not-very-long tutorial that introduces all features of the beamer class package one can use along with its output. Is there any other package which is preferred over beamer?

Comment: Beamer comes with a "compilable tutorial", which seems to be exactly what you want. This tutorial is also available in several languages. And for most situations, beamer is both convenient and produces beautiful output.

Comment: @T.Verron: Googling yielded no result. Could you please tell me where I can find the tutorial you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: The tutorial is the first part of the manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Andrew has already pointed out, you can find a good tutorial in the Beamer User Guide, accessible e.g. on http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer under the link "Package Documentation".

You are interested in Part One, Section 3, *Tutorial: Euclid’s Presentation* on page 21.